# How to convert a list of key-value pair types (from object to string)

Tags: vb.net-2010

How do I convert a list of key-value pairs (String, Object) to a list of key value pairs (string, string)?

Comment: Is this a VB.NET or a C# question? You have both in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, you can do something like this:

```
var newList = oldList.Select(kv => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kv.Key, kv.Value.ToString())).ToList()
```

Of course, the ToString representation may not be exactly what you are expecting if it's some complex type, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = ...
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> castedItemsList = 
 list
    .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Key, item.Value.ToString()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Getting my head around these at the moment and think in future I shouldn't use the object. cheers.

Comment: You should notice that this is not "casted". Calling ToString() returns the type of the underlying class if not overridden. If your "Object" is a string you can cast it using (string)value. If it's not a string take a look at my answer. FYI: It is nice to mark the answer you used. It yields reputation for the answerer and helps later visitors to quickly find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is of type string you can just cast it:

```
var result = source.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(x.key,(string)x.value)
```

If the value needs to be converted you can either use .ToString() as already suggested or use a converter function. Maybe your second object is a Person class with a First and LastName Property and you want to get a full name as result:

```
var result = source.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(x.key, string.Format("{0} {1}", ((Person)x.Value).FirstName, ((Person)x.Value).SecondName))
```

Of course you can use a method to simplify your conversion

```
var result = source.Select(Convert);

private KeyValuePair<string,string> Convert(KeyValuePair<string,object> pair)
{
    var key = pair.Key;
    var person = (Person)pair.Value;
    var fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);

    return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key, fullName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to Cast those objects.